# TWS MakePlan failure with AWSJDB818E

Tags: workload-scheduler

TWS MakePlan is failing with error message: AWSJDB818E 
"AWSJDB818E An internal error has occurred while connecting to the
database. The internal error message is: "CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009"." cannot
 be obtained from the database, or is incorrect.
Which is the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

in that case the error message 
"AWSJDB818E An internal error has occurred while connecting to the
database. The internal error message is: "CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009"." cannot
 be obtained from the database, or is incorrect.

With "internal error message: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009" is an indicator that no DB connections are available.

For TWS 9.4

- Edit the file:
  /WAS/TWSProfile/config/cells/TWSNodeCell/nodes/TWSNode/servers 
  /PSLITE-TIV01/resources.xml
- In the "DB2 Universal Type 4 JDBC Driver DataSource"
  change the value minConnections="1" maxConnections="30" to
  minConnections="0" maxConnections="100"
- A restart of the WAS is required

thanks.